# Prevent bootstrap popover from clearing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use html in my bootstrap 5 popover. I changed code a little bit in order to get html content from specific div (dont want to to use data-bs-content="" attribute).

Current code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// popover 
$("[data-bs-toggle=popover]").each(function(i, obj) {
 var id = $(this).attr('id')
$(this).popover({
   container: 'body',
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
//  trigger: 'focus',
    customClass: '' + id +'-pop',
    sanitize: false,
  content: function () {
       return $('#popover-content-' + id).html(); 
    
    }
});
 

}); // popover each


// update input fields in hidden popover content div
$(document).on('keyup', ".trigger-pop input[type=text]",function () {  
  var inputid = $(this).attr('id');
 var inputdata = $(this).val();
$('#popover-content-trigger').find('#'+ inputid).val(inputdata);
});

// chkbx on/off toggle "fix"
$("#custombutton").on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
   if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                $('label[for="' + id + '"]').removeClass("btn-outline-primary").addClass("btn-primary"); 
    } else {
            $('label[for="' + id + '"]').removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-outline-primary"); 
        

    }
});

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  <body>

   <button type="button" id="trigger" class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mb-2 " data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" >Trigger</button>


<div  id="popover-content-trigger" style="display:none;" >
  <div class="content">
    
     <div class="row popover-header mb-3" style="margin:-16px -16px 0 -16px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="col-12">
    
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="custombutton" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="custombutton">Some option</label>
    
    </div>
    
  </div> 
  
  
   <div class="row justify-content-around">

    <div class="col-12" >
   
   <div class="form-floating  mb-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Input 1" autocomplete="off" >
  <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
   </div> 

  <div class="form-floating  mb-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Input 2" autocomplete="off" >
  <label for="input2">Input 1</label>
  </div> 


    </div>

  </div>
    
    <br>

  </div>
</div>
   



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to remeber all data from popover after it is hidden (input values, checkbox state..).

Currently after popover close its actually "destroyed" and after next initialisation input fields were empty...
How can i fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Asking the same question as a different user does not equate to more answers.  Duplicate of [#67238348](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238348)

Comment: Intention is to set bounty with this one .. thank you

Comment: Hi, you can store values which user typed inside input in localstorage or somewhere in your dom and retrieve it whenever popover open .

Comment: That was my idea also, but, i ran into problems because my html includes some different input types (text, checkboxes etc..) with uniqe ids and when i initialize change on some of them  (checkboxes for example) it wont work correctly because document contains multiple elements with same IDs.. i found the solution and will post it as answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that "do the job" for me. I am not sure if it is best solution but its works fine.

I combined the `shown.bs.popover` and `hide.bs.popover` functions in this case. So,  after initializing the popup script removes the "content holder" div from document (to avoid having multiple inputs with the same ID in the document), but before actual closing popover script  clones the actual popup content and inserts it into the "popup content holder" for future use / initialization.

This way it saves the user changes done inside the popover (text, checkboxes, etc.).
Also, input element with same IDs alweys exist inside document/DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// popover 
$("[data-bs-toggle=popover]").each(function(i, obj) {
 var id = $(this).attr('id')
$(this).popover({
   container: 'body',
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
//  trigger: 'focus',
    customClass: '' + id +'-pop',
    sanitize: false,
  content: function () {
     actualcontent = $('#popover-content-' + id).find(".content").clone()
     return actualcontent
    }
});
 

}); // popover each


$("[data-bs-toggle=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id')

 $('#popover-content-' + id).find(".content").remove()

}); 

$("[data-bs-toggle=popover]").on('hide.bs.popover', function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id')

 var lastcontent = $(document).find('.'+ id +'-pop').find(".content").clone()
 $(lastcontent).appendTo('#popover-content-' + id);

}); 




});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  <body>

   <button type="button" id="trigger" class="btn btn-secondary mt-1 mb-2 " data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" >Trigger</button>


<div  id="popover-content-trigger" style="display:none;" >
  <div class="content">
    
     <div class="row popover-header mb-3" style="margin:-16px -16px 0 -16px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="col-12">
    
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="custombutton" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="custombutton">Some option</label>
    
    </div>
    
  </div> 
  
  
   <div class="row justify-content-around">

    <div class="col-12" >
   
   <div class="form-floating  mb-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Input 1" autocomplete="off" >
  <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
   </div> 

  <div class="form-floating  mb-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Input 2" autocomplete="off" >
  <label for="input2">Input 1</label>
  </div> 


    </div>

  </div>
    
    <br>

  </div>
</div>
   



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone has suggestions regarding this solution feel free to point it.
Best regards.